# Debian Lenny syslog kernel messages

Tags: kernel, debian-lenny, kernel-panic

I've recently got a hard drive swap on my colo'd box. I reinstalled Debian Lenny on the new drive and setup everything. Recently I've been getting these messages from the kernel (viewed on the terminal and later on /var/log/messages:

```
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] Eeek! page_mapcount(page) went negative! (-1)
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831]   page pfn = 6f65b
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831]   page->flags = 100000000000010
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831]   page->count = 0
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831]   page->mapping = 0000000000000000
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831]   vma->vm_ops = 0x0
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] kernel BUG at mm/rmap.c:673!
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] invalid opcode: 0000 [1] SMP
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] CPU 0
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] Modules linked in: ipv6 ext2 loop snd_pcm snd_timer snd soundcore snd_page_alloc serio_raw i2c_i801 rng_core pcspkr psmouse i2c_core video output button intel_agp evdev ext3 jbd mbcache dm_mirror dm_log dm_snapshot dm_mod sd_mod ata_piix ata_generic piix libata scsi_mod dock ide_pci_generic e100 mii ide_core ehci_hcd uhci_hcd thermal processor fan thermal_sys [last unloaded: scsi_wait_scan]
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] Pid: 6527, comm: sshd Not tainted 2.6.26-2-amd64 #1
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff802876b9>]  [<ffffffff802876b9>] page_remove_rmap+0xff/0x11a
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] RSP: 0018:ffff8100b75d1da8  EFLAGS: 00010246
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffe2000185e3e8 RCX: 0000000000008e53
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] RDX: ffff810080a4c000 RSI: 0000000000000046 RDI: 0000000000000282
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] RBP: ffff8100379838c8 R08: 00007f6d11ba4000 R09: ffff8100b75d1800
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000010000000010 R12: ffff8100bb446b00
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] R13: 00007f6d11ba4000 R14: ffffe2000185e3e8 R15: ffff810001023b80
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffffffff8053d000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] CR2: 00007f6d1195b480 CR3: 0000000037904000 CR4: 00000000000006e0
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] Process sshd (pid: 6527, threadinfo ffff8100b75d0000, task ffff8100bd0a0990)
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] Stack:  800000006f65b045 800000006f65b045 ffff8100bc013d20 ffffffff8027f69a
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831]  ffff810100000000 0000000000000000 ffff8100b75d1eb8 ffffffffffffffff
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831]  0000000000000000 ffff8100379838c8 ffff8100b75d1ec0 0000000000296460
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] Call Trace:
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831]  [<ffffffff8027f69a>] ? unmap_vmas+0x4c9/0x885
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831]  [<ffffffff80283ac8>] ? exit_mmap+0x7c/0xf0
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831]  [<ffffffff80232538>] ? mmput+0x2c/0xa2
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831]  [<ffffffff802378ad>] ? do_exit+0x25a/0x6a6
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831]  [<ffffffff802afa45>] ? mntput_no_expire+0x20/0x117
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831]  [<ffffffff80237d66>] ? do_group_exit+0x6d/0x9d
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831]  [<ffffffff80237da8>] ? sys_exit_group+0x12/0x16
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831]  [<ffffffff8020beda>] ? system_call_after_swapgs+0x8a/0x8f
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831]
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831]
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] Code: 80 e8 d7 e5 fc ff 48 8b 85 90 00 00 00 48 85 c0 74 19 48 8b 40 20 48 85 c0 74 10 48 8b 70 58 48 c7 c7 8c 49 4b 80 e8 b2 e5 fc ff <0f> 0b eb fe 8b 77 18 5a 5b 5d 83 e6 01 f7 de 83 c6 04 e9 21 54
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] RIP  [<ffffffff802876b9>] page_remove_rmap+0xff/0x11a
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831]  RSP <ffff8100b75d1da8>
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] ---[ end trace e8a2f3b263482c6e ]---
Mar 22 09:04:29 seedbox kernel: [72710.442831] Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!
```

Everything still works after this but the messages keep showing. I don't know what the problem is or how to debug / track it, hope you guys can help.. let me know if you need more information.

**UPDATE**: Posted the full message from syslog (contains more info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this be relevant?

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=484833

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=501465

http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0710.2/0295.html